# setFilesToUpload is not working for my webpage

Tags: testcafe

test('Uploading', async t => {
await t
.setFilesToUpload('#upload-input', [
'./uploads/1.svg',
'./uploads/2.svg',
'./uploads/3.svg',
])
.click('#upload-button');

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following?

```
test("Uploading files", async (t) => {
  await t.setFilesToUpload("#upload-input", [
    "./uploads/1.svg",
    "./uploads/2.svg",
    "./uploads/3.svg",
  ])
  .click("#upload-button");
});
```

1. Do you see any errors ?
2. Do you see the files are put into the input element ?
3. Do you have the files in the given location from the test file?

Reference : [Test File Upload](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402808/recipes/basics/test-file-upload)

Comment: I don't see any error,

Comment: Yes files are in input tag only

Comment: I have given correct location

Comment: But in my I have only upload link then save button